# Rake routes doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

I have model RecurringIncome

I set routes:

```
resources :recurring_incomes
```

I check routes with rake routes and I see:

```
 new_recurring_income GET      /recurring_incomes/new(.:format)      recurring_incomes#new
```

But:

```
new_recurring_income_path
```

give an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_reccuring_income_path'
```

What's wrong?

html in income/new.html.erb:

```
    <div class='section_button'><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><%= link_to 'Add icome', new_reccuring_income_path %></div>
```

Comment: Show the code, where you used `new_recurring_income_path` ?

Comment: where you try `new_recurring_income_path`?

Comment: <div class='section_button'><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><%= link_to 'Dodaj przychód stały', new_reccuring_income_path %></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo .It should be `new_recurring_income_path`

you have set `resources :recurring_incomes` and you are using `new_reccuring_income_path`.

update your `link_to` as

```
<div class='section_button'><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><%= link_to 'Add icome', new_recurring_income_path %></div>
```

Comment: What typo?? You wrote exackly that same as I

Comment: @Michael Check the spelling.

Comment: @Michael you used `new_reccuring_income_path` but it should be `new_recurring_income_path`.

Comment: table in mysql is recurring_incomes

Comment: @Michael you used **cc**, instead of **c**. and single **r** instead of **rr**...

Comment: @Michael And missed one r too.

Comment: Thanks, i look on it for 20 minutes and do not see this :)

Comment: @Michael You need a break.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `new_recurring_income_path`

Check spelling of `recurring` in new_**reccuring**_income_path